# regex match seems to get stuck or take forever

Tags: python, regex

I had this regex working on other cases, but when we get this sbc file the regex seems to get stuck or takes forever .

```
re.match('^(?P<folder>([a-zA-Z_]+)(\d+)([a-zA-Z_].*)*)\.(?P<authenitcation>.+)\.(?P<user>\w+)-(?P<serial>\d{6})\.sbc$', "baring_dig.1JWDAUTH_IN_PROGRESS.zhaochang-000450.sbc")
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `([a-zA-Z_].*)*` looks strange, did you mean `[a-zA-Z_].*`? `^(?P<folder>[a-zA-Z_]+\d+[a-zA-Z_].*)\.(?P<authenitcation>.+)\.(?P<user>\w+)-(?P<serial>\d{6})\.sbc$`? See https://regex101.com/r/81Wl4C/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, i hope this will be useful:

```
/^[a-z_]+\.\d+[a-z_]+\.*\w+-\d{6}\.sbc$/i
```

[image]

I use this page to test the regex in phyton: https://pythex.org/

https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5Ba-z_%5D%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%5Ba-z_%5D%2B%5C.*%5Cw%2B-%5Cd%7B6%7D%5C.sbc%24&test_string=baring_dig.1JWDAUTH_IN_PROGRESS.zhaochang-000450.sbc&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Answer (score 0):

The `([a-zA-Z_].*)*` part causes catastrophic backtracking, as `[a-zA-Z_]` and `.` can match at the same chars. You need to rewrite the regex as

```py
^(?P<folder>[a-zA-Z_]+\d+[a-zA-Z_].*)\.(?P<authenitcation>.+)\.(?P<user>\w+)-(?P<serial>\d{6})\.sbc$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81Wl4C/1).

Comment: I will add more details if you confirm this is what you need.